# How to pass class template argument to boost::variant?

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I have a template method that uses boost::get of boost:variant module:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, std::string, bool, uint8_t> Variant;

template <class T>
void write(const Variant& t) {
    size_t sizeT = boost::apply_visitor(SizeOfVisitor(), t);
    memcpy(&v[offset], &boost::get<T>(t), sizeT);
}
```

The problem is I know the underlying type of Variant only at runtime. And AFAIK I can query for it only with `which()` method.

Is there any way I can pass the type T, which is the underlying type of Variant to this method?
For instance, using `which()` I do know, what type there is, but how to pass it?

```
switch (m_var.which()) { // Returns an int index of types in the order of passed template classes
    case 0: // This is int
    case 1: // This is std::string
    ...
}
...
Writer.write<???>(m_var); // How to pass the type here?
```

EDIT: If you know any other way to achieve the desired result - actually getting the address of boost::variant inner variable, to copy from there, please share with me your ideas

Thank you

Comment: You cannot `memcpy` an `std::string` value.

Comment: I didn't actually memcpy it. For string I had a separate method to memcpy its content (mystring.c_str()). I think this is allowed, right?

Comment: The way the code in your question is set up, you *will* write a function that (incorrectly) `memcpy`s an `std::string` should it receive an `std::string`-holding variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happen to have written a very similar answer here:

- **[C++: Extract size of boost::variant element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012488/c-extract-size-of-boostvariant-element/27013615#27013615)**

Again, the most important would be that it's ***completely bogus*** to use `memcpy` with non-POD datatypes (so you ***cannot*** use it with `std::string`. Ever).

The way to operate on `variant`s with the type known only at runtime is using `boost::static_visitor<>`.

Here's the example with `main()` adapted to be close to what you wanted to achieve, apparently,

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f07d59bcd016a66)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

#include <boost/array.hpp> // just as a sample
#include <iostream>

namespace serialization {

    namespace customization {
        template<typename T, typename Out, typename R = typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_pod<T>, void>::type>
            void do_serialize(T const& x, Out& out)
            {
                static_assert(boost::is_pod<T>(), "");
                char const* rawp = reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&x);
                std::copy(rawp, rawp+sizeof(T), out);
            }

        template<typename Out>
            void do_serialize(std::string const& x, Out& out)
            {
                do_serialize(x.size(), out);
                for(auto ch : x)
                    do_serialize(ch, out);
            }
    }

    struct serialize_f : public boost::static_visitor<> {
        template<typename Out, typename... T>
            void operator()(boost::variant<T...> const& v, Out& out) const
            {
                boost::apply_visitor(boost::bind(*this, _1, boost::ref(out)), v);
            }

        template<typename T, typename Out>
            void operator()(T const& x, Out& out) const
            {
                using customization::do_serialize; // ADL dispatch
                do_serialize(x, out);
            }
    };

    template <typename T, typename Out>
        Out serialize(T const& v, Out out) {
            const static serialize_f _vis {};
            _vis(v, out);
            return out;
        }

}

namespace MyUserTypes {

    struct A {
        std::string name;
        int i;
    };

    template<typename Out> void do_serialize(A const& v, Out& out) { // ADL will find this
        serialization::serialize(v.name, out);
        serialization::serialize(v.i, out);
    }
}

int main() {
    using namespace serialization;
    std::vector<uint8_t> binary_data;
    auto out_inserter = back_inserter(binary_data);

    // variants and custom types
    typedef boost::variant<MyUserTypes::A, boost::array<char, 42> > V;
    MyUserTypes::A myA { "0123456789", 99 };
    V v = boost::array<char,42>();

    serialize(myA, out_inserter);
    serialize(v, out_inserter);
    v = myA;
    serialize(v, out_inserter);

    std::cout << "Bytes in binary_data vector: " << binary_data.size() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain it how does `boost::apply_visitor(boost::bind(*this, _1, boost::ref(out)), v);` works, that `operator ()` for visitor class is called with T=concrete type (int, float etc). I don't understand it how _1 substitution works here. There is no substitution variable after `bind` function. I checked boost manual, though this part is not clear in docs too.

Comment: @rightaway717 The `apply_visitor` expects [a unary functor (in this case)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/apply_visitor.html). It calls that functor with the concrete element value contained in the variant. Now, because our function expects two arguments, we bind the second to `ref(out)` so a unary bound functor remains that is compatible with `apply_visitor`.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (m_var.which()) { // Returns an int index of types in the order of passed template classes
    case 0: // This is int
      Writer.write<int>(m_var);
    break;
    case 1: // This is std::string
      Writer.write<std::string>(m_var);
    break;
    ...
}
```

:)

Comment: Haha :) That's funny. But this is not the place where I want to write things. I'm writing stuff in another method.

Comment: @rightaway717 The solution is the same, juste move the switch at the place where you want to do your dispatch. You'll need a runtime dispatching method in all cases, and the only improvement to this is to have some kind of map thats maps a value to a type, like a `boost::fusion::map` but the other way, i'm not sure that's even doable in theory so i'm afraid this is the best you will get :)

Comment: If you're going to advocate switching on magic type indices, why not advocate some goto at the same time

Comment: @sehe Well this is the best that comes to my mind, a visitor based solution would probably be better indeed but also implies a lot more boilerplate code ^^

Comment: @Drax the main reason you see "boiler plate" in my answer is because my answer does a lot more (it adds actual serialization to generic output iterators and customization points (`do_serialize`) for custom types). You can simplify if you are willing to stay with the scope of your answer: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9640554/. At least then you don't hard code the type index/type list (which is a nice source of errors and maintenance costs). And it's in just as many lines of code, but without `...` left out lines :)

Comment: @sehe Fair enough you convinced me :) I still find it a little too bad that you have to create a new class, it would be great if we could pass a generic lambda =/

Comment: @Drax I'm pretty sure that's entirely possible if they restrict the use to c++14 and up. In fact, you can already do the plumbing and get "polymorphic" inline visitors defined with just c++11: see [**`make_visitor`** in this old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17776618/85371). The plain code already uses a local struct defined in a lambda - reducing namespace clutter. There's a related variation **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18432618/85371)**. There's still some ironing to do if the result types don't match up.