# Calculate Hash-Value from stream without boost

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, stream

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353643/c-hash-value-of-object-graph-similar-to-boostserialization) I learned that it's possible to create an iostream that hashes its full input.

Though this example here uses boost. Is it possible to do this without boost and if yes, how?

Comment: Do what. Of course. You use another library. What hash anyways? md5? sha1? blake2?

Comment: Ideally the hashing algorithm should be exchangeable, that's why I didn't specify it. Though we can assume md5 here.

Comment: I don't quite understand the rest of your comment. I'm just asking how to do your cool hashing-stream without boost. I don't quite understand how to do it with basic STL streams.

Comment: Use a library. libcrypto, Crypto++, PoCo, and many many more libraries implement these.

Comment: And re. how to get it in `std::ostream` use a custom `std::streambuf`. [@DietmarKuhl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1120273/dietmar-k%C3%BChl) has some rather cool answers showing this (for compression/encryption) IIRC)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. I don't want to have too many dependencies (and increased binary size) - that's also why I avoid boost.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question a little bit? What exactly do you want to hash - and when? With every `flush`?